# How do you apply a function to a nested list?

Tags: r

I need to get the maximum of a variable in a nested list. For a certain station number "s" and a certain member "m", `mylist[[s]][[m]]` are of the form:

```
station date.time        member  bias
6019    2011-08-06 12:00 mbr003  86
6019    2011-08-06 13:00 mbr003  34
```

For each station, I need to get the maximum of `bias` of all members.  For `s = 3`, I managed to do it through:

```
library(plyr)
var1 <- mylist[[3]]
var2 <- lapply(var1, `[`, 4)
var3 <- laply(var2, .fun = max)
max.value <- max(var3)
```

Is there a way of avoiding the column number "4" in the second line and using the variable name `$bias` in `lapply` or a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `[` with the names of columns of data frames as well as their index. So `foo[4]` will have the same result as `foo["bias"]` (assuming that `bias` is the name of the fourth column).

`$bias` isn't really the *name* of that column. `$` is just another function in R, like `[`, that is used for accessing columns of data frames (among other things).

But now I'm going to go out on a limb and offer some advice on your data structure. If each element of your nested list contains the data for a unique combination of `station` and `member`, here is a simplified toy version of your data:

```
dat <- expand.grid(station = rep(1:3,each = 2),member = rep(1:3,each = 2))
dat$bias <- sample(50:100,36,replace = TRUE)

tmp <- split(dat,dat$station)
tmp <- lapply(tmp,function(x){split(x,x$member)})

> tmp
$`1`
$`1`$`1`
  station member bias
1       1      1   87
2       1      1   82
7       1      1   51
8       1      1   60

$`1`$`2`
   station member bias
13       1      2   64
14       1      2  100
19       1      2   68
20       1      2   74
etc.
```

`tmp` is a list of length three, where each element is itself a list of length three. Each element is a data frame as shown above.

It's really much easier to record this kind of data as a single data frame. You'll notice I constructed it that way first (`dat`) and then split it twice. In this case you can `rbind` it all together again using code like this:

```
newDat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(tmp,function(x){do.call(rbind,x)}))
rownames(newDat) <- NULL
```

In this form, these sorts of calculations are *much* easier:

```
library(plyr)
#Find the max bias for each unique station+member
ddply(newDat,.(station,member),summarise, mx = max(bias))
  station member  mx
1       1      1  87
2       1      2 100
3       1      3  91
4       2      1  94
5       2      2  88
6       2      3  89
7       3      1  74
8       3      2  88
9       3      3  99

#Or maybe the max bias for each station across all members
ddply(newDat,.(station),summarise, mx = max(bias))
  station  mx
1       1 100
2       2  94
3       3  99
```

Comment: @Sisse: This was what was alluded to in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247108/problems-splitting-data-frame-into-a-nested-list  There, it was mentioned that the split-apply-combine approach using the whole data might be better depending on what you were going to do with the data.  From this example, it seems that is the case.

Comment: I apologize if I already asked this question, and I thank @joran and any one else for help.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution using repeated `lapply`.

```
lapply(tmp, function(x) lapply(lapply(x, '[[', 'bias'), max))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `[[` instead of `[`, but it should work fine with a string (don't use the `$`).  try:

```
var2 <- lapply( var1, `[`, 'bias' )
```

or

```
var2 <- lapply( var1, `[[`, 'bias' )
```

depending on if var1 is a list.

Comment: Your example will not work without the brackets `[` and `[[` quoted.