# Split data frame, apply function, and return results in a nested list

Tags: r, list, plyr

My question's title almost matches the `dlply` (`plyr` package) description, except for the "nested" part.

Let me explain with an example:

```
library(plyr)
res <- dlply(mtcars, c("gear", "carb"), identity)
head(res, 2)
# $`3.1`
#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# 
# $`3.2`
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Dodge Challenger  15.5   8  318 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# AMC Javelin       15.2   8  304 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# Pontiac Firebird  19.2   8  400 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
```

As you can see, the output is a list where the names (keys) are the concatenation of the two  variables I used for splitting the data, e.g. `"3.1"` is the key for `(gear = 3, carb = 1)`.

Instead, I would like my result to be a nested list so the elements can be accessed through two sets of keys, one for each of my splitting variables: `res[["3"][["1"]]`.

Is there something around, not necessarily from the `plyr` package, that can achieve this? I'd like the answer to be generalizable to any number of splitting variables. Also, it is important that I can apply any function although my example used the `identity` function,  resulting in a mere split of the data. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came with a solution myself, it uses recursion:

```
nested.dlply <- function(df, by, fun, ...) {

   require(plyr)

   if (length(by) == 1) {
      dlply(df, by, fun, ...)
   } else {
      dlply(df, by[1], nested.dlply, by[-1], fun, ...)
   }
}
```

Here are a couple examples:

```
nested.dlply(mtcars, c("gear", "carb"), identity)
# $`3`
# $`3`$`1`
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# 
# $`3`$`2`
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Dodge Challenger  15.5   8  318 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# AMC Javelin       15.2   8  304 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# Pontiac Firebird  19.2   8  400 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
# [...]

nested.dlply(mtcars, c("gear", "carb"), head, 2)
# $`3`
# $`3`$`1`
#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Valiant        18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# 
# $`3`$`2`
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Dodge Challenger  15.5   8  318 150 2.76 3.52 16.87  0  0    3    2
# [...]
```

I doubt this is very efficient but it does the job. I still welcome your suggestions. Ideally I was hoping some package already implemented it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7247108/1270695), but Brian Diggs provided the `plyr` solution there: `dlply(mtcars, .(gear), dlply, .(carb))` and so on, for more nesting. As discussed at that question, such a nested data structure might not be the most convenient to work with.

Comment: Thank you @mrdwab. I think that the only way to generalize the nested `dlply` calls suggested by Brian Diggs is to use a recursion like I have above. The link you provided did help me make my code a bit shorter (edited).

Answer (score 2):

What about nesting `split`?

```
temp = lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$gear), function(x) split(x, x$carb))
temp[["3"]]["1"]
# $`1`
#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: thanks but it does not exactly address my problem, read the end of my question: I need it to be generalized to any number of split variables (not just two), and it needs to apply a function (not just do a split).